# Weird values in params when passing nil as foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, parameters

I'm having some weird problems with rails params. I have two models: Page and NewsItem.

Page:  `has_many :news_items`
and

NewsItem: `belongs_to :page`

In my form for creating new `news_item` I have a list of radio buttons with which I can select a `page` to which newly created item will belong.

Everything is working correctly so far. What is bugging me is:
When I select first option (page has no parent -> value passed should be `nil`) the value actually passed in parameters for `page_id` is `"on"`!

So I have few questions:

1. Since I need to do some checking of the value of params for proper redirecting, I'm wondering can I count on `page_id` using value `"on"` to represent `nil`? Is this a standard way in rails to represent `nil` or is this specific to my setup? Is there a chance that this will change in future versions?
2. As you can see in hash from console on the bottom of the post, after selecting `nil` as a value to pass as foreign key (`page_id`), the value actually set as page_id is not `nil` but `0`. Is this a good way of stating that this item does not belong to a page, or should I try to force the value to be `nil`?  Should I be passing a value of zero instead of `nil`?
   Is there a chance for a table to have a row with primary id of zero?

I'm running this in development, on rails 4.0.4 with sqlite

Here is the part of the form with radio buttons:

```
  <ul>
      <li>
          <%= f.radio_button :page_id, nil %>
          <%= f.label :page_id, t('page_no_parent'), value: nil %>
      </li>
      <% @parents.each do |page| %>
          <li>
              <%= f.radio_button :page_id, page.id  %>
              <%= f.label :page_id, page.name, value: page.id %>
          </li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Here is the actual params hash from request:

```
Started PATCH "/hr/admin/news_items/37" for 127.0.0.1
Processing by Admin::NewsItemsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blablablablablaabllba",
"commit"=>"Save content to page", "news_item"=>{"name"=>"test new", 
"title"=>"", "body"=>"", "author"=>"", "page_id"=>"on"}, 
"locale"=>"hr", "id"=>"37"}
```

And here is item hash from console:

```
2.0.0p353 :124 > NewsItem.find(37)
NewsItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "news_items".* FROM "news_items" WHERE "news_items"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 37]]
=> #<NewsItem id: 37, name: "test new", url: nil, title: "", body: "", author: "",
page_id: 0, user_id: 7, created_at: "nvm", updated_at: "nvm">
```

Please note that I tried to google this, but couldn't find anything...

UPDATE:

The way i realized this was happening was because I have following routes:

```
  resources :pages do
    resources :news_items, except: [:index, :show]
  end
  resources :news_items
```

I was trying to enable CRUD for `:news_items` both with and without `page_id` in url. So after a delete I was trying to redirect to a proper route depending on values in `params`.

```
if params[:news_item].key? :page_id and not params[:news_item][:page_id].nil?
    admin_page_path(Page.find(params[:news_item][:page_id]))
else
    admin_news_items_path            
end
```

So if `:page_id` is not `nil` route to corresponding page, else route to `NewsItem#index`.
But I kept getting an error saying:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Admin::NewsItemsController#update
Couldn't find Page with id=on
```

**If I pass zero instead of nil, everything works as expected. Is this a good way to represent that a row does not have foreign key?**

Comment: I'm a bit confused about one thing regarding the `page_id: 0`: Are you setting the value `0` whenever `page_id` = "on" yourself? Or is that happening without your involvement?

Comment: No, it's happening completely without my involvement. I'll update the questing with a snippet that made me realize this was happening.

Comment: In case my update is even more confusing than helping, everything was working correctly without my involvement. If I selected `nil` the `page_id`s would be set to zero automatically, and everything would work. Problems started after I used that routing snippet in the question update.